# Call Back Method for Task.Run()

Tags: c#

at the moment my code is getting very repetitive. I have to raise my busy indicator repeatedly throughout the software.

The three actions are

```
1. Raise Busy Indicator
2. Do the actions
3. Turn Off Busy Indicator
```

Example

```
public async void OpenAttachment()
{
    Events.PublishOnUIThread(new BusyEvent { IsBusy = true });
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            if (SelectedAttachment == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var tempFile = string.Format(
                "{0}\\{1}.{2}", Path.GetTempPath(), SelectedAttachment.FileName, SelectedAttachment.FileExtension);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, UnitOfWork.FileRepository.GetFileBytes(SelectedAttachment.Id));

            Process.Start(tempFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Notification.Error("Person - Opening attachment", "File couldn't open, please close last file instance.");
        }
    });
    Events.PublishOnUIThread(new BusyEvent { IsBusy = false });
}
```

I'm looking to run a method such that it'll execute the busy indicator without having to repeat it everytime.

Something like

```
public async void OpenAttachment()
{
    Execute(() => await Task.Run(() => {....TaskWork});
}
```

Wondering if someone can give me tips on how to reduce this repeated code.

Comment: C# use delegators for it... take a look to the docu...

Comment: If you need just callback, then you can use good old `ContinueWith()`.

Comment: Do not use `async void`, it is only allowed to be used to make your method signature compatible with a event handler. Your function does not appear to be a event handler so it should be doing `async Task` instead.

Comment: It is an event handler, I'm using Caliburn Micro and it makes things alot easier. @ScottChamberlain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
public async Task RunBusyTask(Action task)
{
    Events.PublishOnUIThread(new BusyEvent { IsBusy = true });
    await Task.Run(task);
    Events.PublishOnUIThread(new BusyEvent { IsBusy = false });
}
```

---

```
RunBusyTask(() => {...});
```

Comment: I would make it a `async Task` not a `asnyc void` so you could do `await RunBusyTask(() => {...});`. Asnyc void should only be used to make your method signature be compatible with a event handler.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Good point, it's usually better to return `Task`, unless you need the method for an event.

Comment: You should really just accept a `Task`, or a `Func<Task>`, because the task may not represent CPU bound work.